# Nginx + PHP7.0-fpm – PHP errors #500 go into the status code header and into the browser console. Error log is not written

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, 500-error, php7

I am using Nginx + php7.0-fpm. Some of my errors (500 code) go into the status code header. In the browser console I see, for example, such a message:

> POST https://example.com 500 (DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2017-04-09 :) at position 11 (:): Unexpected character)

I tried disabling error reporting, `display_errors = off` does not work as well – errors go to the header, and they are never logged. The nginx error log is clear. But not all errors are risen like that – most of them are handled correctly. I have the `fastcgi_intercept_errors` directive enabled in the `nginx.conf`.

When I switch back to php5, I do not see such behaviour. The problem is only when I use php7.0. Can't figure out how to make errors go into the log instead of the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PHP7, but when `nginx` receives a message over the STDERR channel of the FastCGI interface, it will write it to its error log.

You should check your PHP configuration files. It is common to log PHP errors to a separate logfile, but if you must send these error messages to `nginx` try changing the `display_errors` variable to `stderr`.

See [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Check if You have set error_log in php.ini. 
Also You can add following to .conf file as PHP7 has some stupid defaults

```
catch_workers_output = yes

php_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

Comment: I tried using these directives before I wrote this post, and it does not help.